# Тире при пропущенном слове

Tags: тире

Необходимо ли ставить тире в предложении:

*Пусть эмоции всегда будут положительными, жизнь (—) счастливой, а невзгоды обходят стороной.*

После слова «жизнь» напрашивается глагол, его нет. Нужно ли вместо него поставить тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 5. Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза:
>
>    ```
>    Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно плохо (Т.); За окном вагона плыла кочковатая равнина, бежали кустарники, дальние — медленно, ближние — вперегонку (А. Т.); Голоса офицеров с каждой минутой становились громче, слова — резче, аргументы — непримиримее (Гол.); Мир освещается солнцем, а человек — знанием (Посл.); Подберите ещё несколько примеров, каких — не имеет значения; У него в глазах — как бы поскорее отделаться от меня; Теперь я понимаю, чем он всех привлекает, — непреклонностью; Мы взялись за дело весело, они — даже с энтузиазмом; Трудно было установить, кто из них был прав, кто — виноват (ср. без вспомогательного глагола: Трудно было установить, кто прав, кто виноват); Одни голосовали за предложенную резолюцию, другие, наоборот, — против (ср.: Одни голосовали за, другие против); Идти дальше через трясину было опасно, оставаться — тоже; Такую температуру могут выдержать только сплавы стали, а из лёгких металлов — только сплавы титана; Предстояли большие строительные работы, а главное — сооружение водопровода; Вы здесь уже давно, а я — только несколько дней; Одни работают, донимая своё дело как общее для всех, другие — стараясь извлечь выгоду только для себя; Пассажиры… рассовывали чемоданы, сумки, свёртки, переносили подушки, кто — чтобы лечь головой от окна, кто — чтобы головой к окну (Роз.); Карманы были двойные: внутренний — из полотна, внешний — из серого коленкора (Юг.); Один атом натрия замещает один атом водорода, один атом цинка — два атома водорода, а один атом алюминия — три атома водорода.
>    ```
>
> При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится:
>
> ```
>    Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку (Ч.); Из нашей батареи только Солёный пойдёт на барже, мы же со строевой частью (Ч.); Алёша смотрел на них, а они на него (Дост.); У вора один грех., а у нас с хозяином десять (Остр.); …Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие (Леон.).
> ```
>
> *[[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91)]*

Предложение *«жизнь (—) счастливой»* является неполным — в нём отсутствует сказуемое. Это предложение является частью сложного предложения, и возможно восстановить пропущенное сказуемое ***«будет»*** по первой части фразы:

*«…эмоции … **будут** положительными, жизнь **[будет]** счастливой».*

Ставить тире или нет, зависит от наличия паузы.

На мой взгляд, это предложение произносится с паузой, поэтому тире нужно:

*«Пусть эмоции всегда будут положительными, жизнь — счастливой, а невзгоды обходят стороной».*

Answer (score 0):

Тире необходимо: пропущенное сказуемое, есть союз, который подчёркивает, что это не простое перечисление. В таком варианте тире можно было бы опустить. *Пусть эмоции всегда будут положительными, жизнь счастливой, невзгоды обходят стороной*.

Comment: _«…есть союз, который подчёркивает, что это не простое перечисление»_ — вы могли бы дать ссылку на это правило?